# Where can I find information about the binary format of anchor instructions?

Tags: anchor

I'm trying to write a program that describes a Solana transaction containing anchor instructions, so that humans can read it.

When I get to the anchor instruction data within the Solana TX I know that the first 8 bytes are the discriminator that tells anchor which of my rust functions to call, after that I suppose we have the parameters passed into that function, but...

- what format are they in?
- are arrays prefixed with their size?
- are integers interpreted big-endian or little-endian?

Basically, where is the documentation that will explain all of the above and more?

Answer (score 1):

They are in Borsh format, which you can read about here: https://borsh.io/

Comment: Cheers, I have figured out a lot about the binary format, but the question is "Where is the anchor documentation that provides this?" Also, I'm not sure that's entirely correct, because borsh serialization puts a 4-byte size before arrays, whereas anchor doesn't if you pass in a fixed-size array.

Comment: Borsh only puts the 4-byte size before dynamic sized arrays